# JSF ResourceBUndle change using image?

Tags: image, jsf-2, resourcebundle

I've stumbled upon [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/) tutorial and decided to try it out :-).

In the tutorial, they use a List with a valuechangelistener to change the language when something else was chosen.

I'm wondering how the same could be achieved for changing lanuage by clicking on an image?

```
<h:graphicImage url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flag-3/16/Netherlands-    Flag-icon.png" value="#{languageController.localeCode}" onclick="submit()"/>
```

obviously didn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you basically want an `<a><img /></a>`? Just put the image inside a `<h:commandLink>`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{languageController.setLocaleCode('nl')}">
        <h:graphicImage name="images/nl-flag.png" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

I'm assuming that your environment supports Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2.